# How to convert multiple codepoint emoji back into a single grapheme in python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm new to python and creating a whatsapp chat parser and using regex to find all the message data from a .txt file for analysis.

The regex pattern I'm using finds all the message text but converts emoji with modifiers into their individual parts, eg: ‍♀️ is displayed like this '\u200d♀️'.

How can I convert these sequences of unicode back into their original single graphemes so I can save them to a sqlite3 database?

Here is the regex I'm using to find all the message data:

`FULL_MESSAGE = "(\[([\d/]+), ([\d:]+.{3})\]) (.+?): (\X+)"`

Here is an example of the kind of data I am trying to parse

`[26/9/2015, 12:05:18 am] David: ‍♀️ haha, I didn't even know those emojis existed!!!`

Here is the code I'm using to find emojis in a string:

```
import regex
import emoji

def emoji_count(message):
    emoji_list = ''
    data = regex.findall(r'\X', message)
    for word in data:
        if any(char in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI_ENGLISH for char in word):
            emoji_list += word
    return emoji_list
```

I have a feeling I need to do some sort of encode/decode but I can't find a definitive answer.

EDIT - After more testing I found that the .split() method I've been using to read in the txt file might be causing some of the errors, or maybe it's about the emoji being put into a list of strings, like this:

text file

```
[29/12/2021, 5:21:20 pm] Person1: Testing ‍♀️
[19/9/2015, 11:23:12 am] Person2: Testing with this one 
[25/9/2015, 9:14:31 pm] Person1: ... ✋
```

Code

```
import emoji
import regex

with open('_chat.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read().split('\n')

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(text, file=f)
```

Output:

```
['[29/12/2021, 5:21:20 pm] Person1: Testing \u200d♀️', '[19/9/2015, 11:23:12 am] Person2: Testing with this one ', '[25/9/2015, 9:14:31 pm] Person1: ... ✋']
```

Code (no .split())

```
import emoji
import regex

with open('_chat.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(text, file=f)
```

Output:

```
[29/12/2021, 5:21:20 pm] Person1: Testing ‍♀️
[19/9/2015, 11:23:12 am] Person2: Testing with this one 
[25/9/2015, 9:14:31 pm] Person1: ... ✋
```

Comment: Need to add imports:  `import regex` also where does the variable `emoji` come from please ?   questions in this format are optimal:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Oops, have added those modules in now. Thanks!

Comment: The “sequence of Unicode” *is* the grapheme. Rendering as a single graphic is a function of the terminal used.  There’s nothing to convert.

Comment: But why does it save that sequence as individual graphemes to a txt file instead of the original grapheme? Also after more testing I noticed that the way I read the file into to a variable splits the emoji up into its parts. I'm using with 
open('file', 'r') as f:
chat = f.read().split('\n')
but if I use just f.read() the emojis stay the same. However I need to have them split into separate lines for my regex to work...

Comment: Then use f.readlines()

Comment: readlines() still returns a list, which seems to be what is breaking the emoji up into its modifiers. I think I've found a workaround by converting the list back into a string but it's not good. Thanks tho!